# Compile Ada program for Linux using Windows

Tags: windows, linux, ada

If I want to compile a program that is written in Ada, I have to use GNAT, of course.

As my Computer has Windows as its sole operating system, I cannot use GNAT, normally. Right? Thus I got Cygwin which enables me to use GNAT on Windows.

But the result is an executable that runs under Windows - not Linux. So how can I compile the Ada code for Linux although I only have Windows? (Please don't think about the reasons ...)

Is this possible with Cygwin? Do I have to install a virtual machine with Linux? Or is there another (easier) solution to this issue?

Comment: Perhaps not a virtual machine, but have you considered a dual boot machine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have to use GNAT, of course.

Not true; there are other Ada compilers.  (GNAT is the only one I know of that's free.)

Running GNAT under Cygwin gives you Cygwin executables, which are Windows executables that depend on `cygwin1.dll`.  They will *not* work on Linux.  See the "What ... isn't it?" section on the [Cygwin home page](http://cygwin.com/).

There is a GNAT for Windows.  The GNAT Pro version has a list of supported platforms [here](http://www.adacore.com/home/products/gnatpro/supported_platforms/); it includes Linux and Windows, but it doesn't show a Windows-to-Linux cross compiler.

Since GNAT is free software (GNAT Pro <strike>isn't</strike> is a little more complicated; I won't get into that) there could well be a Windows-to-Linux GNAT cross-compiler -- or, if you're *really* ambitious, you could build one yourself (or hire someone to do it for you).

But installing GNAT on a Linux system is the easiest approach.  It doesn't *have* to be a virtual machine.  If you have the hardware, you can install some Linux system by itself, or you can set up a dual-boot system on your Windows box.  Ubuntu has a Windows installer, [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer), that installs an Ubuntu image as a Windows file; it doesn't let you run Windows and Ubuntu concurrently, but it lets you dual-boot without having to repartition.

There are other options; these are just the ones I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible with Cygwin?

It's probably *possible*.

> Do I have to install a virtual machine with Linux? Or is there another (easier) solution to this issue?

Installing a Linux on a virtual machine is likely to be the simplest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Since GNAT is free software (GNAT Pro isn't; I won't get into that) there could well be a Windows-to-Linux GNAT cross-compiler -- or, if you're really ambitious, you could build one yourself (or hire someone to do it for you).

Actually GNAT Pro is Free Software, free as in freedom, not as in beer.

And I think that it would be simplest to install Linux in virtual machine and compile with it.

Comment: See also [Free Software: A Viable Model for Commercial Success—R. Dewar](http://video.fosdem.org/2012/maintracks/janson/Free_Software__A_Viable_Model_for_Commercial_Success.webm).

Comment: If you has posted that as a comment on my answer, I would have seen it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

AdaCore has a gnat compiler for the Windows operating system freely available at: http://libre.adacore.com/libre/download/ and choose "Free Software..." and click "Build Your Download Package" and go from there.  As Keith Thompson suggests, you can setup a dual-boot solution if you actually need a Linux compatible executable.  Remember any program compiled on Windows results in a Windows-only executable unless you have a compiler that allows for cross-compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It became possible for them who use Windows 10 64 bit with new "[Linux Subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-win10)" feature. You may install gnat on it and use it to compile ELF binaries, as well as windows binaries.